# "Is Tom drawing the picture" and "Is Tom drawing a picture"

Tags: meaning, difference, articles, present-tense, present-continuous

Sorry for maybe stupid question. "Is Tom drawing the picture" and "Is Tom drawing a picture". Do I understand correctly that the first means "I see a picture. I want to know who is drawing it" but the second "I want to know what is Tom doing now "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, when on says

> Is Tom drawing **a** picture?

It implies that you are wondering whether Tom is drawing a picture or drawing something else.

For the second one, when one says

> Is Tom drawing **the** picture?

It implies that you want to know whether Tom is drawing a **specific** picture that you are referring to, hence the use of "**the** picture".